# Sails js Error in file Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, sails.js

I have a form which have a input type file with name "uploadfile". No error occurs while a file is selected and form is submitted. But having this error while I don't select a file and submit the form.

`

```
if(req.file('uploadfile')._files.length>0){
                var ques_file  = req.file('uploadfile');
                console.log('here');
                ques_file.upload({ 
                  saveAs: function(file, cb) {                       
                            cb(null, file.filename);
                          },
                  dirname: dirPath },function (err, files) {
                  if (err){                        
                    return res.serverError(err);
                  }else{                     
                    name =files[0].filename;
                    filename=name;                     
                    console.log("file : "+filename);

                  }
                });
```

`
And in commad having this error

```
 events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ETIMEOUT: An Upstream (`NOOP_ques_uploadfile`) timed out waiting for file(s). No files were sent after waiting 10000ms.
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\kucbt_admin\node_modules\sails\node_modules\skipper\standalone\Upstream\Upstream.js:62:15)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use if statement for `req.file()`, you can check the length of array inside the `function whenDone` as in example below:

```
req.file('avatar').upload({
      saveAs: function(file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.filename);
      },
      dirname: uploadPath
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) { //onUploadComplete
      if (uploadedFiles.length==0) {
        //if no file selected.
        sails.log.info('nothing selected');
        return res.view('showimage');
      }
      if (err){
        return res.serverError(err);
      } else{
        return res.view('showimage', {file:uploadedFiles});
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing 0.5.5 of Skipper- the default ETIMEOUT timer was extended.  Also in past versions, ETIMEOUT issues for many users were coming from multiparty form upload errors (i.e. unknown content-type) that were getting eaten by the ETIMEOUT.

To install skipper@0.5.5, you can directly bring it in as the bodyparser in your project by doing `npm install skipper --save` in your project and [configuring it as middleware](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware), or you can just install Sails v0.11.x, which comes with the updated version.

As of today, Sails v0.11 is released with the "beta" tag on npm, so you can install it directly in your project using:

`npm install sails@beta --save`

Comment: I installed skipper and tried, it didn't worked. Again I installed sails@beta still not working. Having same  error.